# Datagrid add new item when the Blank Row gains focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I would like my `<DataGrid/>` with `CanUserAddItems="true"` to instatiate the new `ItemVM` when the Blank Row *gains focus* intead of the default behaviour, to create new `ItemVM` when the blank row is first *edited*. Or in other words, I would like to change the default `DataGrid`'s workflow from:

1. User enters Blank Row
2. User presses F2
3. New `ItemVM` gets instantiated

to custom workflow that does not require explicitly edit the Blank Row first:

1. User enters Blank Row
2. New `ItemVM` gets instantiated

it is not important at which point the new `ItemVM` is added to bound `ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGrid` class uses a private [AddNewItem](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGrid.cs,88450648e9370715,references) method to instantiate the underlying data object.

If you get a reference to the row container for the placeholder, you could handle its `GotFocus` event and call the `AddNewItem()` method using reflection:

```
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow newItemPlaceholderRow = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder);
    if (newItemPlaceholderRow != null)
        newItemPlaceholderRow.GotFocus += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            typeof(DataGrid).GetMethod("AddNewItem",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                .Invoke(dg, null);
        };
}
```

Note that `AddNewItem()` is undocumented and may be modified or removed in future versions, but if you really want to modify the behvaiour of the built-in the control, the other option would probably be to create your custom own one.

Comment: Are you handling the `Loaded` event for the `DataGrid`? There is no container before it has been loaded.

Comment: my mistake, added loaded handler to the wrong DataGrid (had multiple datagrids in test project for the problem).